# How to make a custom alert dialog that is called using a method instead of embedding into parent view?

Tags: react-native

How to make a custom alert dialog that is self destroyed when dismissed and called from any where in the app with a static method. Same as in react-native method

> alert()

My current code:

```
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Portal, Dialog } from 'react-native-paper';

static function showDialog(title, paragraph, buttonLabelText, onDismissHandler, canDismiss) {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Portal>
            <Dialog dismissable={canDismiss} visible={need a value here} onDismiss={() => {this.onDismissHandler()}}>
                <Dialog.Title>{title}</Dialog.Title>
                <Dialog.Content>
                    <Paragraph>{paragraph}</Paragraph>
                </Dialog.Content>
                <Dialog.Actions>
                    <Button onPress={() => {this.onDismissHandler()}}>{buttonLabelText}}</Button>
                </Dialog.Actions>
            </Dialog>
        </Portal>
      </View>
    )
}


export default { showDialog };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React-native has it's on `Alert` and you can use like below.

```
import { Alert } from 'react-native';
import _ from 'lodash';

export const showPopupAlert = (message, onOKPressed: _.noop) => {
    Alert.alert(
      '',
      message,
      [
        { text: 'OK', onPress: onOKPressed },
      ],
    );
};

export const showOptionAlert = (message, buttonOk, buttonCancel, action, title) => {
  Alert.alert(
    title,
    message,
    [
      { text: buttonOk, onPress: action },
      { text: buttonCancel },
    ],
    { cancelable: false },
  );
};
```

Save this as `ShowAlert.js` as root laval component and call like below.

`import { showPopupAlert } from 'yourpath/ShowAlert';`

`showPopupAlert('Your message');` // Call like this

Comment: @0x01Brain Add comment if have query.

Comment: Thanks this is what I am looking for, but how to modify style for Alert? like change background for example or text color?